# Trouble with integrating $\frac{\arctan (x)}{x}$

Tags: definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I have a function $F(x)$ that is defined as $\int_0^x f(t) dt$ which I'm trying to find the limit of when $x$ approaches infinity. Previously in the assignment, the function $f(x)$ was defined as being $$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac{\arctan (x)}{x}, &x \neq 0, \\
1, &x = 0. 
\end{cases}
$$
I'm having trouble integrating $\frac{\arctan (x)}{x}$. when I try to see the result in Wolfram Alpha, I get a result with imaginary numbers and polylogarithms both of which aren't part of our course.

So I was wondering if I have misunderstood the task completely, or if there is some trick to integrating $\frac{\arctan (x)}{x}$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to find a way to solve the problem without doing the integration. What do you know about the arctangent as $x\to\infty$?

Comment: the limit of the arctangent as x approaches infinity is pi divided by two. So the limit of $(arctan x)/x$ is 0 since x is much greater than arctan x. So the integral of that has to be infinite if i'm not mistaken, but i'm not sure how sound that reasoning is.

Comment: @Kracobsen: _why_ is the integral of that infinite?  In fact, the fact that the limit as $x$ goes to infinity of $f(x)$ (in this case, using $f(x) = \arctan(x)/x$) is 0 is a necessary condition for the integral to _not_ be infinite!  But it's not a sufficient condition - that is, even if $f(x)$ goes to 0, its integral can still be infinite; you need to justify that that's what happens here.

Comment: If $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$, then $\lim_{x \to \infty} \int_0^x f(t) \: dt$ can be finite or infinite. Consider the cases $f(t) = 1/(1+t^2)$ (finite integral) and $f(t) = 1/(1+t)$ (infinite integral). Which of these cases does $f(t) = \arctan(t)/t$ resemble more closely?

Comment: Do you know about the comparison test for convergence of infinite series? Do you reckon there might be some similar technique for improper integrals?

Answer (score 2):

Use Taylor [series representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Infinite_series) for $\arctan$:
$$
   \frac{\arctan(x)}{x} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k}}{2k+1} x^{2k}
$$
and integrate term-wise, for $0<x<1$:
$$ \begin{eqnarray}
   \int_0^x \frac{\arctan(t)}{t} \mathrm{d} t &=& \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k}}{(2k+1)^2} x^{2k+1} = x \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-x^2)^{k}}{k!}  \frac{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_k \cdot \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)_k \cdot k!}{\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)_k \cdot \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)_k}  \\ &=& x \cdot {}_3 F_2\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}, 1; \frac{3}{2}, \frac{3}{2}; -x^2 \right)
\end{eqnarray}
$$
wher $(a)_k := a(a+1)\cdots(a+k-1)$ denotes [Pochhammer symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_symbol) and ${}_pF_q$ denotes [generalized hypergeometric function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function).  For $x>1$, we split the integration range $(0,x)$ into $(0,1)$ and $(1,x)$ and perform a change of variables $t \to 1/t$ in the second integral:
$$\begin{eqnarray}
    \int_0^x \frac{\arctan(t)}{t} \mathrm{d} t &=&  \int_0^1 \frac{\arctan(t)}{t} \mathrm{d} t + \int_1^{x} \frac{\arctan(t)}{t} \mathrm{d} t \\
 &=& \int_0^1 \frac{\arctan(t)}{t} \mathrm{d} t + \int_{1/x}^1 \frac{\arctan(1/t)}{t} \mathrm{d} t
\end{eqnarray}
$$
Using the identity $\arctan(t) + \arctan(1/t) = \frac{\pi}{2}$ which holds for $t>0$, we have:
$$\begin{eqnarray}
    \int_0^x \frac{\arctan(t)}{t} \mathrm{d} t &=&  \int_0^1 \frac{\arctan(t)}{t} \mathrm{d} t + \int_1^{x} \frac{\arctan(t)}{t} \mathrm{d} t \\
 &=& \int_0^{1/x} \frac{\arctan(t)}{t} \mathrm{d} t + \frac{\pi}{2} \int_{1/x}^1 \frac{1}{t} \mathrm{d} t \\
  &=&  \frac{\pi}{2} \ln(x) + \frac{1}{x} \cdot {}_3 F_2\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}, 1; \frac{3}{2}, \frac{3}{2}; -\frac{1}{x^2} \right)
\end{eqnarray}
$$
As a corollary, $\int_0^x \frac{\arctan(t)}{t} \mathrm{d}t$ diverges logarithmically as $x$ grows large. Of course, this can be determined by much simpler means, as in Gerry's answer.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{x}{\arctan\pars{t} \over t}\,\dd t&=\ln\pars{x}\arctan\pars{x}
-\int_{0}^{x}{\ln\pars{t} \over t^{2} + 1}\,\dd t
\\[3mm]&=\ln\pars{x}\arctan\pars{x}
-\lim_{\mu\to 0}\partiald{}{\mu}\int_{0}^{x}{t^{\mu} \over t^{2} + 1}\,\dd t
\\[3mm]&=\ln\pars{x}\arctan\pars{x}
-\lim_{\mu\to 0}\partiald{}{\mu}\int_{0}^{x}{t^{\mu/2} \over t + 1}\,\half\,t^{-1/2}\,\dd t
\\[3mm]&=\ln\pars{x}\arctan\pars{x}
-
\half\,\lim_{\mu\to 0}\partiald{}{\mu}
\int_{0}^{x}{t^{\pars{\mu - 1}/2} \over t + 1}\,\dd t\tag{1}
\end{align}

> With
> $\ds{\xi \equiv {1 \over t + 1}\quad\iff\quad t = {1 \over \xi} - 1}
>      = {1 - \xi \over \xi}$
> \begin{align}
> \int_{0}^{x}{t^{\pars{\mu - 1}/2} \over t + 1}\,\dd t&=
> \int_{1}^{1/\pars{x + 1}}\xi\pars{1 - \xi \over \xi}^{\pars{\mu - 1}/2}\,
> \pars{-\,{\dd \xi \over \xi^{2}}}
> \\[3mm]&=
> \int^{1}_{1/\pars{x + 1}}\xi^{-\pars{\mu + 1}/2}\pars{1 - \xi}^{\pars{\mu - 1}/2}\,
> \dd \xi\\[3mm]&={\rm B}\pars{{1 - \mu \over 2},{1 + \mu \over 2}}
> -{\rm B}_{1/\pars{x + 1}}\pars{{1 - \mu \over 2},{1 + \mu \over 2}}\tag{2}
> \end{align}
> where ${\rm B}\pars{p,q}$ and ${\rm B}_{x}\pars{p,q}$ are the *Beta* and the
> *Incomplete Beta* functions, respectively. ${\rm B}\pars{p,q}$ satisfies
> $\ds{{\rm B}\pars{p,q} = {\Gamma\pars{p}\Gamma\pars{q} \over \Gamma\pars{p +} q}}$
> such that
> $$
> {\rm B}\pars{{1 - \mu \over 2},{1 + \mu \over 2}}
> ={\Gamma\pars{1/2 - \mu/2}\Gamma\pars{1/2 + \mu/2} \over \Gamma\pars{1}}
> ={\pi \over \sin\pars{\pi\bracks{1/2 + \mu/2}}}
> ={\pi \over \cos\pars{\pi\mu/2}}
> $$
> $\pars{2}$ is reduced to:
> $$
> \int_{0}^{x}{t^{\pars{\mu - 1}/2} \over t + 1}\,\dd t
> =\pi\sec\pars{\pi\mu \over 2}-{\rm B}_{1/\pars{x + 1}}\pars{{1 - \mu \over 2},{1 + \mu \over 2}}
> $$
> In terms of the *Hipegeometric Function*:
> $$
> \int_{0}^{x}{t^{\pars{\mu - 1}/2} \over t + 1}\,\dd t
> =\pi\sec\pars{\pi\mu \over 2}
> -
> 2\,{\pars{1 + x}^{\pars{\mu - 1}/2} \over 1 - \mu}\
> _{2}{\rm F}_{1}\pars{{1 - \mu \over 2},{1 - \mu \over 2};{3 - \mu \over 2};
>                      {1 \over x + 1}}
> $$
> and
> \begin{align}
> &\lim_{\mu \to 0}\partiald{}{\mu}
> \int_{0}^{x}{t^{\pars{\mu - 1}/2} \over t + 1}\,\dd t
> \\[3mm]&=-\,\bracks{\ln\pars{1 + x} + 2}\arcsin\pars{1 \over \root{1 + x}}
> \\[3mm]&\phantom{=}-
> \\[3mm]&\phantom{=}
> {2 \over \root{1 + x}}\lim_{\mu \to 0}\partiald{}{\mu}\
> _{2}{\rm F}_{1}\pars{{1 - \mu \over 2},{1 - \mu \over 2};{3 - \mu \over 2};
>                      {1 \over x + 1}}
> \end{align}

The answer is found by replacing this expression in $\pars{1}$.